# $n$ insects on $|z|=1$ "occupy" a point if the product of their distances to it is at most $1$. How much of $C$ can they occupy?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization

> The Devourers of the Unit Circle
>
> There are $n$ tiny insects living on the unit circle $C = \{z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|=1\}$. They act as a swarm and "occupy" a point $w$ if the product of distances from $w$ to each of them is at most $1$. I.e if the insects are at points $z_j$ they occupy the set
>
> $$\left\{w\in C : \prod_{j=1}^n |w-z_j| \leq 1 \right\}$$
>
> How much of $C$ can they occupy at most?

[Here's an interactive version of the picture below](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5vhbvpc5rl) (Put the points you want to be active to the list $P_{ts}$.)

[image: insects at points A_j the occupied area shown in green]

---

*Here's what I've done so far.*

Let the insects be at points $e^{ia_j}$ for $0=a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \dots \leq a_n \leq 2\pi$. Denote $f(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n |z-z_j|$. Let's study

$$g(t) = \prod_{j=1}^n |e^{it} - e^{ia_j}|^2 \\
= \prod_{j=1}^n \left|e^{-i\frac{t+a_j}{2}} \right|^2|e^{it} - e^{ia_j}|^2 \\
= \prod_{j=1}^n \left|e^{i\frac{t-a_j}{2}} - e^{-i\frac{t-a_j}{2}}\right|^2 \\
= \prod_{j=1}^n 4\sin^2 \left( \frac{t-a_j}{2} \right) \\
= 4^n \prod_{j=1}^n \sin^2 \left( \frac{t-a_j}{2} \right)
$$

Now, for the occupied area to be one connected blob, in the edge case we need to find $t_1, t_2 \dots, t_{n-1}$ where $g'(t_j) = 0$ and $g(t_j) = 1$ (these are the points where the level set $f=1$ is tangent to the unit circle.

**EDIT**
I think it's better to have the middle one (if $n$ odd) at $1$ and then others in conjugate pairs so we can collapse the pair $|(e^{it}-e^{ia})(e^{it}-e^{-ia})|^2$ into $(\cos t - \cos a)^2$ and the formulas come a bit simpler.

With the formula of WimC's answer I made this picture of how the devouring evolves as more insects arrive:

[image: Evolution of Devouring, vol20]

Here's the Sage-code (better version):

```
def getQ(n):
    a = 4^(1/n)
    return 2*a^(-n) * (1 + (1 if n%2 else -1) * chebyshev_T(n,x)(a*(x-1)+1) )

#can find the roots directly
def getRootsOfQ(n):
    a = 4^(1/n)
    #cos(theta) = a*(x-1)+1
    return [N((cos(pi*((2*m+(1-n%2))/n))-1)/a+1) for m in range(n)]

def makePic(n):
    
    x_coords = getRootsOfQ(n)
    x_coords = sorted(list(set(x_coords)))
    pts = [(x1, sqrt(1-x1^2)) for x1 in x_coords] + [(x1, -sqrt(1-x1^2)) for x1 in x_coords[:(-1 if n%2 else len(x_coords))]]
    p = lambda x,y: prod((x-b[0])^2+(y-b[1])^2 for b in pts)
    lim = 1-2*4^(-1/n)
    
    g = Graphics()
    g += circle((0,0), 1, color='black')

    var('y')
    g += contour_plot(p, (x, -1.2, 1.2), (y, -1.2, 1.2), contours=[1], fill=False)
    g += points(pts, color='blue', pointsize=40)

    return g

makePic(100).show(figsize=6)
```

Comment: Great question, great interactive illustration! From playing around with the points, it seems that the maximum might occur when the insects are all in the same place. A line of approach might be to first prove this for $n=2$.

Comment: @joriki Thanks. If you put them all in one point, the occupied area is a circle of radius 1, since a power of a positive number is $1$ is equivalent to the number being $1$. And you can get that already with $n=1$. I think with two points the maximum comes with (assume $z_1 = 1$) $z_2 = e^{i\frac{2pi}{3}}$. For three points, if you place them so that a contiguous area is occupied, I solved $\cos \alpha$ to be $1-\frac{3}{2\sqrt[^3]{4}}$ in the following picture: https://membolicsythodhome.files.wordpress.com/2020/05/distprod1.png?w=600 (My solution is in that blog, but it's in Finnish )

Comment: You should have included that prior work in the original question (please see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) in the meta thread on [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)). It would be good if you could translate the most important points to English and include them here. (I tried it with Google Translate, but it's hard to understand; and DeepL doesn't know Finnish yet.)

Comment: @joriki I edited. It's basically the way I solved it for three points (assuming the solution is given when the occupied area is indeed one connected blob). You get a set of equations where the parameters $a_j$ and $t_j$'s can be solved. I modified it a little bit towards the general case, assuming you start at $1$ and then the other points go to positive direction from there. In my original thinking I took $1$ to be the middle one, since the angles are equal by symmetry.

Comment: Why do you think that $z_2=\mathrm e^\frac{2\pi\mathrm i}3$ yields the maximum? My simulation shows that this only yields an area about $0.84$ times the area of the unit circle, which is roughly in agreement with what your nice animation shows if you set $z_2$ to that value.

Comment: @joriki Ah, I see. My question was about devouring as much of the **arc** of the unit circle as possible. I see $C$ (no pun intented :D) wasn't a good notation. But that would be another interesting question: what configurations maximize the area.

Comment: I see. Well, the notation $C$ together with the wonderful graphical illustration of the area gave a wrong impression :-)

Comment: The pictures are a nice visual addition. Really looks like the unit circle is gobbled up with increasing $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the following construction is optimal (for a contiguous occupied arc). I did not look at your linked page so it may be the same as your work.

Assuming $P(z) = \prod(z-z_k) = z^n + \ldots + (-1)^n$ is a real polynomial (i.e. its roots are conjugacy symmetric). Then there is a real polynomial $Q(x) = (-2)^n x^n + \ldots$ such that $$Q(\frac{z+z^{-1}}2)=\lvert P(z) \rvert^2$$ for all $z\in C$. For $n$ even one can take $$Q(x) = 2\alpha^{-n}\left(1+T_n(\alpha(x-1)+1)\right)$$ where $\alpha = 4^{1/n}$ and $T_n$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind) of the first kind. Then $Q$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$ on the interval $[1- 2 \alpha^{-1}, 1]$. The roots of the polynomial $P$ in this case occupy an arc of angle $\beta$ where $\cos(\beta/2) = 1-2 \alpha^{-1}$.

If $n$ is odd then one can take $$Q(x) = 2 \alpha^{-n} (1 - T_n(\alpha(x-1)+1))$$ again with $\alpha=4^{1/n}$  and find the same interval $[1-2 \alpha^{-1},1]$ on which $Q$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: My linked calculation was only about the case $n=3$. Yes, it certainly looks like the connected-case is the optimal one. I also suspect the minimal case to be when the insects are at n-th roots of unity(?)

Comment: No, even for the case $n=3$ the roots of $P$ other than $z=1$ are not roots of unity. In fact its minimal polynomial is $$4 - 24 z + 60 z^2 - 53 z^3 + 60 z^4 - 24 z^5 + 4 z^6$$ which is not cyclotomic (it has roots of modules $\neq 1$).

Comment: I was talking about the minimal case (when mentioning the roots of unity). Aren't the roots of P what give the maximal case?

Comment: Ah, the minimal case, I misunderstood. Need to think about that.

Comment: Could you say a bit about why you suspect that this construction is optimal?

Comment: @joriki For one, it coincides with the observations of OP. Moreover, if a local maximum of $Q$ would be strictly less than $1$ then one can spread the roots still a little bit further, raising that maximum toward $1$. And of course, Chebyshev polynomials are always involved.  ;-)